# Android password requested after fastboot

Tags: fastboot, password

I am trying to reset an intel machine with android 5.0 using fastboot.

If I do a complete reset, I have no problem, it encrypts normally & boot & works as a charm.
But what I need is to reset the machine while keeping the data, so I removed this command:
fastboot format data

After booting the machine I got a screen saying "to start android, enter your password"
whatever last password enetered, I get the folowing (as if the password is wrong) & start resetting the machine..it works well, but no data is there too.
I have no idea to what password does it means nor any of my known passwords work.
Any Solution?

Comment: usually, 12345678 works in such cases, unless u have put up something else

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But it still asks to reset the machine no other option :( Can you help me please, it's an intel cpu.

Answer (score 0):

what happened with me is not a full solution, just a partial:
I connect the device to a keyboard via a USB & then we can switch using the arrows to move to android booting.
Too bad we will have to connect it to this keyboard each time we restard the android device.
But at least you can can now save your stuff, before loosing the device.